# htaccess : redirect if path is an encoded string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a domain on which I run a personal file hosting service for my clients. Recently I had to use the domain to host a site and move the service to a subdomain. However I would like to preserve the 1000's of links I've created.

I was thinking of doing it with htaccess and writing a rule like this although I am hardly even a newbie when it comes to Regex strings :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/[regex]$ http://subdomain.website.com/$1
```

Where [regex] would somehow detect that the string is a 12 character encoded string. Ex :

```
0G0C2V251p2t
2f243p3T0D34
```

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-z]{12}` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't that be [0-9a-zA-Z]{12} (capital Z) ? 

So.. 301 ^/[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}$ http://subdomain.website.com/$1 then ?

Comment: Indeed it should be a capital Z; sorry about that typo on my end.

Comment: I did RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}$ http://sub.my.com/$1 and it just redirects to http://sub.my.com/   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on what you want `$1` to be, because it is defined as the first group in your regex.  Assuming you want the target to be "/encodedString", then you would do `([0-9a-zA-Z]{12})` as your regex.

Comment: And how would I match a string that contains 12 OR 20 characters. I tried {12,20} but that just matches anything between 12 and 20 characters.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to shorthand "n OR m" length: `([0-9a-zA-Z]{12}|[0-9a-zA-Z]{20})`.  I think I'll post a question about "n OR m" length actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([A-Za-z0-9]{12}([A-Za-z0-9]{8})?)$ http://subdomain.website.com/$1
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9]{12}([A-Za-z0-9]{8})?)$ http://subdomain.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```